# Losing my count with Arrays and Function Calling

Tags: c++, arrays, function

In my current code, I attached the prompt at the top. I'm having a hard time with either my High or Low values. I believe the problem is in the Function being called, rather than my int main(), but I could be wrong. The lowest value is not the one being recorded. It seems to default either in the middle or the end of the array (June or December are common months to be outputted for my Low, my High is often correct)

Any ideas on how I could resolve this issue?

```
/*
Write a program that lets the user enter the total 
rainfall for each of 12 months into an array of 
doubles. The program should calculate and display 
the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly 
rainfall, and the months wit hthe highest and lowest 
amounts.

Input Validation: Do not accept negative numbers 
for monthly rainfall figures.

*/

include <iostream>
include <iomanip>
include <string>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
double RainTotal(double[], int);
double RainAverage(double[], int);
double RainHighpoint(double[], int);
double RainLowpoint(double[], int);


int main()

{
    int count;                              //counting variable for loops
    const int Size = 12;

    double RainInput[Size];                 //Numerical variables
    int RAINHIGHEST, RAINLOWEST;
    double RAINTOTAL, RAINAVERAGE;
    string Month[] = { "January", "Febuary", "March", "April",          //Must list string names for each month
        "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
        "November", "December" };



    cout << "Please enter the average rainfall with the corresponding month\n\n";
    for (count = 0; count < Size; count++)
    {
        cout << Month[count] << " : ";                                  //User prompted to enter rainfall values
        cin >> RainInput[count];
        while (RainInput < 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a positive number for " << Month[count] << endl;
            cin >> RainInput[count];
        }
    }

    RAINTOTAL = RainTotal(RainInput, Size);                             //Call Total Rainfall
    RAINAVERAGE = RainAverage(RainInput, Size);                         //Call Average Rainfall

    string LowMonth, HighMonth;                                         //String value for given High/Low Months
    double LowPoint, HighPoint;                                         //Values stored for highest and lowest rainfall

    RAINLOWEST = RainLowpoint(RainInput, Size);                         //Call Lowest Array Subscript Value
    LowMonth = Month[RAINLOWEST];
    LowPoint = RainInput[RAINLOWEST];

    RAINHIGHEST = RainHighpoint(RainInput, Size);                       //Call Highest Array Subscript Value
    HighMonth = Month[RAINHIGHEST];
    HighPoint = RainInput[RAINHIGHEST];

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "The Total Rainfall is: " << RAINTOTAL<<endl;
    cout << "The Average Rainfall is: " << RAINAVERAGE << endl;
    cout << LowMonth << " had the least rainfall all year with " << LowPoint << endl;
    cout << HighMonth << " had the most rainfall all year with " << HighPoint << endl;
    return 0;
}

double RainTotal(double RainInput[], int size)
{
    double Total = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)                      //Find the Total Rainfall
    {
        Total += RainInput[count];
    }
    return Total;
}

double RainAverage(double RainInput[], int size)
{
    double Total = 0;
    double Average;
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)                      //Find the Rainfall Average
    {
        Total += RainInput[count];
    }
    Average = Total / size;

    return Average;
}

double RainLowpoint(double RainInput[], int size)
{
    double LowPoint = RainInput[0];
    int LowCount = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)                          //Find Lowest rainfall month through numerical comparison
    {
        if (RainInput[count] <= LowPoint)
        {
            LowCount = count;
        }
    }
    return LowCount;
}

double RainHighpoint(double RainInput[], int size)
{
    double HighPoint = RainInput[0];
    int HighCount = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)                          //Find Highest rainfall month through numerical comparison
    {
        if (RainInput[count] >= HighPoint)
        {
            HighCount = count;
        }
    }
    return HighCount;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a [SSCE*](http://sscce.org/) that still demonstrates your problem. Further, please elaborate on what is happening within the code, and what you've tried to fix it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to update the current highest and lowest point in your loops, rewriting your two function like below should solve the issue.

```
double RainLowpoint(double RainInput[], int size)
{
    double LowPoint = RainInput[0];
    int LowCount = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)  //Find Lowest rainfall month through numerical comparison
    {
        if (RainInput[count] <= LowPoint)
        {
            LowCount = count;
            LowPoint = RainInput[count]; // was missing
        }
    }
    return LowCount;
}

double RainHighpoint(double RainInput[], int size)
{
    double HighPoint = RainInput[0];
    int HighCount = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)  //Find Highest rainfall month through numerical comparison
    {
        if (RainInput[count] >= HighPoint)
        {
            HighCount = count;
            HighPoint = RainInput[count]; // was missing
        }
    }
    return HighCount;
}
```

You could also just drop your custom code and use <algorithm> from the std library [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: You also do not need to start your loop at zero since you're already doing that in the initialization.   In other words, I believe you could optimize by doing:  "int count = 1".

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your LowPoint and HighPoint variables:

```
if (RainInput[count] <= LowPoint)
{
        LowCount = count;
        LowPoint = RainInput[count];
}
```

...

```
if (RainInput[count] >= HighPoint)
{
        HighCount = count;
        HighPoint = RainInput[count];
}
```